# Integrate email capture with Google form

Tags: email, google-forms

I am trying to integrate Google Forms with my site to capture email addresses of interested users; however, I'm presented with a `Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist` error message.

[This is my website](http://foundersconnect.io/).

Any ideas how to fix? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Although the link is helpful, please consider editing your question and including any theories you have on what may be causing the problem, steps you've taken to correct the issue, and other information that may help potential answerers.  As it stands, your question is vague.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are just embedding the form is will be as easy as pasting the embed link then updating positioning  to show up on your site correctly.  Make sure you make the form public so anyone can access it.